# My website's label doesn't show on firefox

Tags: php, html, google-chrome, firefox, label

The web site i'm working on works perfectly on Chrome, but when I open it in Firefox  the text between label tags don't show up.

Can anyone help me?

EDIT:
This is my code.

```
echo " <div class='row form-row' id='form-specialties'>
    <label for='specialties'>" . $_dic['#SPECIALTIES#'] . " </label>
    <input id='form-specialties' class='form-input' name='specialties'                value='$specialties'>
</div>";
```

This is the code on FireFox:

```
<label for="specialties"> </label>
```

This is the code on Chrome:

```
<label for="specialties">Especialidades </label>
```

Comment: You need to at least show the offending markup/code.

Comment: @AlexK. i've edit the post. Is that what you were talking about?

Comment: You could show us the resulting html code in the browser itself. The label could be empty. Use the browser's developer tools to check CSS properties!

Comment: @DanielBrunneri've edit the post with the info you've said. Thanks!

Yes on FireFox the label is empty, but i've no idea why... That's my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I notice you have duplicate ID's in your markup (`form-specialties`). In HTML, an ID must be unique; it may not be used multiple times. Perhaps this causes an issue?

Also, it could be helpful to see the CSS you use, perhaps the problem lies in there.

Comment: I've removed the double id and it doesn't work...

I have on that page like 10 textareas and the label show on the first ones, so i don't think it's  a CSS problem...

Comment: Could you post the parsed HTML output? And how is `$_dic` populated? If you would do a `var_dump($_dic)`, is the output different in different browsers?

Comment: the     $_dic is an array used to make the translation between diferent languages in our site. The var_dump on the label did nothing...

Sorry, wath do you mean with 'parsed HTML output'?

Comment: it was in fact a css problem and a '$_dic' problem.